# Install SQL Server Analysis Services w/ SQL Server 2019 Developer

Tags: sql-server

I want to install an instance of SQL Sever Analysis Services locally for development use. The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services) indicates that this can be done with the installation exe, but I can't find that option when I run the developer exe from the [installation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) site.

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016) indicates that it should be available.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
Download the installer
Select custom installation
Choose the 1st link to add features to an existing installation and follow the link.